# Add Certificate To Inserted Files To An .APK

Tags: android, digital-certificate, apk, android-install-apk

I need to add some files to an existed .apk file but after I insert files manually into the .apk file and try to install the program, it shows this error and can't be install:

```
Package <my package> has no certificares at entry assets/myAddedFile.dat; ignoring!
```

How can I add certificate to the added files manually?

Comment: You'll have to resign the entire app again. I do not see why you would want to do it this way, if its your own app, so it probably isn't and that's exactly why this won't work.

Comment: I wrote an app which use an existed .apk file as a template and it's resources should be added by the user by another program and the second program exports the final apk file as a result. how can I resign the entire app again manually?

Comment: "how can I resign the entire app again manually?" -- the same way that you signed it the first time. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: The first time EClipse did :D